# React Native returns response error code 500

Tags: react-native

I just installed node js and react native in windows 10. When i tried to import the new screen (HomeScreen.js), i am getting response code 500. If i remove the import option, it start to work again.

**App.js code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import HomeScreen from 'HomeScreen';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**HomeScreen.js code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> textInComponent </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**package.json file**

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the App.js code, try to write the relative path of HomeScreen.js.

You are doing:

```
import HomeScreen from 'HomeScreen';
```

Try do that:

```
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen'; 

// The ./ is the relative path of file.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your import statement is wrong.

If you want to import your own components you have to search in the folder where you have set it up.

Example if you have app.js at root lvl and the Homescreen.js is in a Screens folder:

```
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';   // no need to say ".js"
```

if you want to call something inside the screens folder for example another component living in a component folder you would have to back out of the folder and enter the new one with "../" (two dots and slash)

```
import OwnComponent from "../components/OwnComponent"
```

Side note: If you only have one file inside a folder that you call "index.js" you can import it like this:

```
import Server from "../server"    instead of import Server from "../server/index"
```

Good luck at learning React Native.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe it's because of the forgotten ; in HomeScreen.js?

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> textInComponent </Text>
            </View>
        ) << here.
    }
}
```

I noticed you had it in the default one in App.js